# how to change my vm instance operating system

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to change the operating system of my vm instance in google cloud computing engine, my current is ubuntu 16.10 and I would like to change to 16.04 LTS. what are the steps so that I will totally erase the ubuntu 16.10 and replace it to 16.04.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest is to delete the VM completely, then re-create it and select a boot disc with Ubuntu 16.04. You can do it very easily from Console.

Answer (score 2):

In the google cloud web gui:

1. stop the VM
2. click on the VM
3. edit

   - Storage

     - Boot disk

       - detach boot disk
       - add new disk

         - choose OS
4. save
5. start VM

You can then delete the old boot disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve your data, follow those steps:

1: [Snapshot from disk.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots)
2: delete your instance.
3: create a new instance with your desired version.
4: [add your old disk to your new instance.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk)

Then move your files from the attached disk to the system disk.